# can we divide One Time Setup fee monthly in Recurly?

Tags: recurly

I would like to take one time setup fee each month(first 12 months).
For example: if $1000 is the one time setup fee, I would like to collect each month $83 from the users for 12 months and next year it will stop collecting.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this by default since setup-fees are designed to offset startup costs of a subscription (like shipping a one time product). My recommendation would be to script something up that adds an $83 adjustment to the account each month (https://dev.recurly.com/docs/create-a-charge-or-credit). This charge would be rolled into the subscription invoice each month.

Comment: Thanks, ill go through it